# In Azure, I cannot see subscription to which I am assigned the Owner role, but I can choose the subscription when creating a VM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-subscription

I have been assigned the Owner role to 3 subscriptions:

1. prod
2. dev
3. test

All three subscriptions have the same configurations. The only difference is their ID and name.

In my Azure portal, when I click the subscriptions sections, I can only see one subscription - the dev one.

However, when creating a VM, I can see all three subscriptions in the dropdown when selecting the subscription.

What is going on?

This looks so much like an Azure bug... but I can't believe it.

---------------- UPDATE -----------------

I am pretty sure this is an Azure bug:
In Home --> Subscriptions, I can only see dev subscription.
However, in Home --> Management groups, I can see all three subscriptions under the Tenant Root Group.

There is nothing I could thing of that is making the dev subscription different from the other 2, except for their names and IDs.

What the hell!

Comment: In the Subscriptions blade, click on the Show all subscriptions link and check.

Comment: @VenkatV  I am having a hard time understanding your comment. I do not see Show all subscriptions link  anywhere.

Comment: In the Subscription blade, click on all subscriptions link : https://i.imgur.com/9imz6kU.png

Comment: @VenkatV Thank you. Oh my god this is so frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is nothing I could thing of that is making the dev subscription different from the other 2, except for their names and IDs.

It is possible that the `subscriptions` that you want to see are hidden. To check if this is the case, click on the  **Subscriptions**  tab and then select  **Show all subscriptions**. If the subscriptions that you want to see are listed, then they are not hidden.

To check all subscriptions in the portal, navigate through the following steps.

**Azure Portal > Subscription > select filter.**

[image]

Comment: this indeed is very frustrating. Thank you bro